# Understanding boosting in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I've been using ElasticSearch for a little bit with the goal of building a search engine and I'm interested in manually changing the IDFs (Inverse Document Frequencies) of each term to match the ones one can measure from the Google Books unigrams.

In order to do that I plan on doing the following:

1) Use only 1 shard (so IDFs are not computed for every shard and they are "global")

2) Get the `ttf` (total term frequency, which is used to compute the IDFs) for every term by running this query for every document in my index

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/index/document/id_doc/_termvectors?pretty=true' -d '{
  "fields" : ["content"],
  "offsets" : true,
  "term_statistics" : true
}'
```

3) Use the Google Books unigram model to "rescale" the `ttf` for every term.

The problem is that, once I've found the "boost" factors I have to use for every term, how can I use this in a query?

For instance, let's consider this example

```
"query":
{  
    "bool":{  
        "should":[  
            {  
                "match":{  
                    "title":{  
                        "query":"cat",
                        "boost":2
                    }
                }
            },
            {  
                "match":{  
                    "content":{  
                        "query":"cat",
                        "boost":2
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Does that mean that the IDFs of the term "cat" is going to be boosted / multiplied by a factor of 2?

Also, what happens if instead of search for one word I have a sentence? Would that mean that the IDFs of each word is going to be boosted by 2?

I tried to understand the role of the `boost` parameter (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/query-time-boosting.html) and `t.getBoost()`, but that seems a little confusing.

Answer (score 2):

The boost is used when query with multi query clauses, example:

```
{  
    "bool":{  
        "should":[  
            {  
                "match":{  
                    "clause1":{  
                        "query":"query1",
                        "boost":3
                    }
                }
            },
            {  
                "match":{  
                    "clause2":{  
                        "query":"query2",
                        "boost":2
                    }
                }
            },
            {  
                "match":{  
                    "clause3":{  
                        "query":"query1",
                        "boost":1
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

In the above query, it means `clause1` is three times important than `clause3`, `clause2` is the twice important than `clause2`, It's not simply multiply `3`, `2`, because when calculate score, because there is **normalized** for scores.

also if you just query with one query clause with `boost`, it's not useful.

**An usage scenario for using boost:**

A set of page document set with **title** and **content** field.

You want to search **title** and **content** with some terms, and you think **title** is more important than **content** when search these documents. so you can set **title** query clause boost more than **content**. Such as if your query hit one document by **title** field, and one hit document by **content** field, and you want to hit **title** field's document prior to the **content** field document. so **boost** can help you do it.

Comment: thank for the answer! I was wondering, however, if there's a way to boost specific words. On the ElasticSearch guide they mention `t.getBoost()` to do that, but I don't understand how that can be used in practice.

Comment: @Brian, `t.getBoost()` means when we set `boost` in query, the calculation function will get this `boost` by this method `t.getBoost`. and the `boost` is for increase the query clause's weight,

Comment: ok, thanks! but how exactly is "boost" used in the score? This is the description of the score in Lucene (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/practical-scoring-function.html), but it's not clear to me what happens when there's more than one term in the query.

Comment: `t.getBoost` is used when calculate the document score(like the tf idf factor), Do you mean multi terms query or multi query clause?

Comment: I mean a multi-term query. What would the `boost` parameter do in that case? Is that multiplying the tf * idf factor in the scoring formula?